# How to download SalesForceDesk attachments using webclient in c#

Tags: c#, salesforce

I want to download the attachments from my cases to the local folder using c# code. I tried below code.

```
string url= https://simpleaudio.desk.com/api/v2/cases/8/attachments/8897101/url

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  client.DownloadFile(url, @"F:\" + image.jpg);
}
```

But it shows Unauthorized Exception, how to access SalesForceDesk using webclient, i tried a lot please help me to resolve this issue.

and i tried passing access tokens

```
var collection = new NameValueCollection();
collection.Add("username", "********");
collection.Add("password", "********");

byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues("https://simpleaudio.desk.com/login/new", "POST", collection);
```

it is also throws Unauthorized Exception..

Comment: The message is clear. You probably either need to be logged into the site directly or pass in some sort of token in the URL. Either way, that's something you need to figure out, it's not much of a programming issue.

Comment: Log in with an admin account and make sure you enabled token access if you're using a token, or password access if you're using your password.